# how can I add/remove class on children element

Tags: javascript, html, css

See the code below:

```CSS
.nk-section-icons {
    height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.nk-section-icons .nk-sec-container {
    r
}

.nk-sec-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    margin: bottom: 10px;
}

.nk-sec-container.addClass {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nk-section-l-icons">
                <div class="nk-section-icons fav" data-title="Favorites">
                    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-fav-c">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nk-section-icons recent" data-title="Recent">
                    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-recent-c">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nk-section-icons notifs" data-title="Notifications">
                    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-notif-c">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```js
const hrdBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".nk-section-icons")
hrdBtn.forEach((hrdBtns)=> {
    hrdBtns.addEventListener("click", (container)=> {
        const btnContainer = container.currentTarget.children[0]

        btnContainer.classList.toggle("addClass")
    })
})
```

```css
.nk-section-icons {
    height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.nk-section-icons .nk-sec-container {
    r
}

.nk-sec-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    margin: bottom: 10px;
}

.nk-sec-container.addClass {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nk-section-l-icons">
                <div class="nk-section-icons fav" data-title="Favorites">
                    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-fav-c addClass">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nk-section-icons recent" data-title="Recent">
                    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-recent-c">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nk-section-icons notifs" data-title="Notifications">
                    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-notif-c">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can anyone help me, Currently my javascript is working it's adding and removing the class `addClass`? But I need to click the button again to remove the `addClass`. My goal is I want my code if I click the 2nd button the `addClass` in my children's first div will remove and it will be transferred to the 2nd button children's div.

Comment: in your event handler select all the elements you want to "reset" their state and just remove that class to all of them (or filter which one has it and remove it only from there with classList.remove(). That's just before toggling the class to the element triggering the event

Comment: all good now I've resolved the problem thanks guy, By adding this inside the addEventListener the problem is solved

        hrnBtncontainer.forEach(items => {
            items.classList.remove("show")
        })

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hrdBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".nk-section-icons")
hrdBtn.forEach((hrdBtns)=> {
    hrdBtns.addEventListener("click", (container)=> {
    
        // new code: remove active state on all others
        hrdBtn.forEach(button => button.children[0].classList.remove('addClass'))
        
        const btnContainer = container.currentTarget.children[0]

        btnContainer.classList.toggle("addClass")
    })
})
```

```css
.nk-section-icons {
    height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.nk-section-icons .nk-sec-container {
    r
}

.nk-sec-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    margin: bottom: 10px;
}

.nk-sec-container.addClass {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nk-section-l-icons">
                <div class="nk-section-icons fav" data-title="Favorites">
                    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-fav-c addClass">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nk-section-icons recent" data-title="Recent">
                    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-recent-c">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nk-section-icons notifs" data-title="Notifications">
                    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-notif-c">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you will only have one element with `addClass`, you can select the element with `document.querySelector(".addClass")` and remove the class.

```js
const hrdBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".nk-section-icons")
hrdBtn.forEach((hrdBtns)=> {
  hrdBtns.addEventListener("click", (container)=> {

    document.querySelector(".addClass").classList.remove("addClass");

    const btnContainer = container.currentTarget.children[0];
    btnContainer.classList.toggle("addClass");
  })
})
```

```css
.nk-section-icons {
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/*.nk-section-icons .nk-sec-container {
  r
}*/

.nk-sec-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  margin: bottom: 10px;
}

.nk-sec-container.addClass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nk-section-l-icons">
  <div class="nk-section-icons fav" data-title="Favorites">
    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-fav-c addClass"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nk-section-icons recent" data-title="Recent">
    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-recent-c"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nk-section-icons notifs" data-title="Notifications">
    <div class="nk-sec-container nk-sec-notif-c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```